# OptionSetValue does not contain constructor which takes one argument

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, silverlight-5.0

I am creating a silverlight application as a web resource for CRM 2011. Now i am creating a ServiceAppointment record in DB and after creating it i want to change its Status to "reserved" instead of requested.

I googled about this and come across the examples like [Close a Service Activity Through Code](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b77ed5a0-fc16-45c1-9147-34fad248bdd7/close-a-service-activity-through-code-crm-2011)  and [Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.SetStateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.setstaterequest.aspx)

They all suggesting to use "SetStateRequest" and for using this i have to set the OptionSetValue like

```
request["State"] = new OptionSetValue(4);
```

But above line gives me error saying "OptionSetValue does not contain constructor which takes one argument"
BTW i am using SOAP end point of CRM 2011 service in silverlight application

Any ideas friends?

EDIT

Following is my code

```
   var request = new OrganizationRequest { RequestName = "SetStateRequest" };

    request["State"] = 3; 
    request["Status"] = 4;
    request["EntityMoniker"] = new EntityReference() { Id = createdActivityId, LogicalName = "serviceappointment" };

    crmService.BeginExecute(request,ChangeActivityStatusCallback,crmService);
```

And my callback function is 
    private void ChangeActivityStatusCallback(IAsyncResult result) {

```
        OrganizationResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = ((IOrganizationService)result.AsyncState).EndExecute(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _syncContext.Send(ShowError, ex);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you take a screenshot of your optionsetvalue constructor?

Comment: What is the namespace of the OptionSetValue in your first code block?  If you're going to not use the OptionSetValue, you need Text values of the statuses, not int, so "Active", not 1 or "1"

Comment: OptionSetvalue' full qualified name is    MayProjectNameSpance.Silverlight.Common.crmSdk.OptionSetvalue

Answer (score 0):

You must some how be referencing some other OptionSetValue class that is not the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk` one.  Try appending the namespace to see if that resolves your issue:

`request["State"] = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue(4);`

Also, why are you using late bound on the SetStateRequest?  Just use the SetStateRequest class:

```
public static Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.SetStateResponse SetState(this IOrganizationService service,
    Entity entity, int state, int? status)
{
    var setStateReq = new Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.SetStateRequest();
    setStateReq.EntityMoniker = entity.ToEntityReference();
    setStateReq.State = new OptionSetValue(state);
    setStateReq.Status = new OptionSetValue(status ?? -1);

    return (Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.SetStateResponse)service.Execute(setStateReq);
}
```

Comment: I am not using Xrm.Sdk rather i am using Organization SOAP service end point in my silverlight application. And the OptionSetValue class i am getting is, coming from CRM's Organization service reference.

Comment: @ManishPandey Ahh, didn't see that. I believe you can also just set the text value of the state, rather than the optionsetvalue.  Why don't you give that a try?

Comment: @ManishPandey Does this work? `request["State"] = new OptionSetValue{ Value = 4};`

Comment: i have edited my question and posted my code below in my question

Comment: I have also tried this request["State"] = new OptionSetValue{ Value = 4} but that also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daryl for you time and effort. I have solved my problem with the way u have suggested.

I am posting my code that worked for me.

```
        var request = new OrganizationRequest { RequestName = "SetState" };

        request["State"] = new OptionSetValue { Value = 3 };
        request["Status"] = new OptionSetValue { Value = 4 };

        request["EntityMoniker"] = new EntityReference() {  Id = createdActivityId, LogicalName = "serviceappointment" };

        crmService.BeginExecute(request,ChangeActivityStatusCallback,crmService);

private void ChangeActivityStatusCallback(IAsyncResult result) {

        OrganizationResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = ((IOrganizationService)result.AsyncState).EndExecute(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _syncContext.Send(ShowError, ex);
            return;
        }
    }
```